# Scroll bar is not working while click on scroll area in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, grid, scrollbar

I am creating a scrollbar to move grid horizontally. When I'm using firefox as the default  browser it's working fine. If I use Internet Explorer, the scroll area is not working/disabled. I need to display a scrollbar to move my grid left or right but while I am clicking on pane it doesn't move. Here is my code snippet:

Horizantal scroll bar:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <div style="height: 17px; width: 100%;  overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;">
      <div style="height: 1px; width: 1790px;">
        </div>
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

 vertical scroll bar:

  <table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <div style="height: 17px; width: 100%;  overflow-x: hidden ; overflow-y: scroll;">
      <div style="height: 1px; width: 1790px;">
        </div>
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

i used same coding for vertical and horizontal. but horizontal scroll bar is not working.But vertical is working fine

Comment: can u post ur Grid view code and full Html code..? you need Browser compatability code right.? post ur code clearly...

Comment: Hi R1 actually my requirement is to click scroll area and get offsetLeft value. Scroll click is only not working not with grid

Comment: Are you sure this works in FF? I don't think the horizontal scrollbar is doable with 100% width on the table. http://jsfiddle.net/dNtsn/1/

Answer (score 0):

set the position of the scrolling div to relative

Comment: First off: why? What is the exact difference when setting the positioning to relative in this case and how would it be set correctly? What about punctuation? ;) Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yogesh give a proper measurements of Div,Table[tr,td] / what ever ur using.Else use the Styles or Css it will be useful to you.

If u set div Height and width properly the alignment problems will not come try to understand that.You must aware of Html codes.Follow the html Standards.

otherwise First use Google. It will be better.

Comment: Hi R1 please the modified code. but why my vertical scroll bar is working fine.